# How to add icons to MaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native

I have an app in React Native v3. I have MaterialTopTabNavigator with text. It's working fine. But I need to add icons above text of tabs.
https://pasteboard.co/IuTpjGz.png

I have tried this (CommonIcon is my element, but I have also tried Icon from react-native-elements), but it's not working and VScode says ''CommonIcon' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.'
When I run it in emulator, I got SyntaxError.

```
HomeScreen:{
    screen:HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel:"Home",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <CommonIcon name="ios-bookmarks" size={20}/>
      )
    },
  },
...
tabBarOptions: { 
    showIcon: true 
  },
```

So my question is, how to createMaterialTopTabNavigator in React Native 3 with both labels and icons?

Comment: there is a props `tabbaricon` , we can set icon using this props easily , https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html#tabbaricon , let me know if there is an issue.

Comment: you are using `tabBarIcon` but prop is `tabbaricon` .

Comment: Show me the screen of the CommonIcon you made by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague figured it out.
You should not put *navigationOptions* to the *createMaterialTopTabNavigator*. They belong to the page you want to go. In that page, you can specify options for it.

**Main Page and Tab Navigator**

```
export const IndraMainPage = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    MarketTab: MarketPage,
    TradesTab: TradesPage,
    OrdersTab: OrdersPage,
    EventsTab: EventsPage,
    ReportsTab: ReportsPage,
  },
  {
    order: ['ReportsTab', 'TradesTab', 'MarketTab', 'OrdersTab', 'EventsTab'],
    initialRouteName: 'MarketTab',
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    backBehavior: 'none',
    lazy: true,
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      upperCaseLabel: false,
      activeTintColor: COLOR_PRIMARY,
      inactiveTintColor: COLOR_TEXT,
      showIcon: false,
      tabStyle: {height: 55, flexDirection: 'column', padding: 0, paddingTop: 10},
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(250,250,250)',
      },
      indicatorStyle: {backgroundColor: 'transparent'},
    },
  },
);
```

**and then the specific page**

```
export default class EventsPage extends Component<EventsPageProps, EventsPageState> {
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarVisible: true,
    tabBarLabel: ({tintColor}: TabBarLabelProps) => (
      <CenteredColumn>
        <CommonIcon name="calendar" size={20} color={tintColor ? tintColor : COLOR_TEXT} />
        <CommonText xs style={{color: tintColor ? tintColor : COLOR_TEXT}}>
          Events Tab
        </CommonText>
      </CenteredColumn>
    ),
  };

...
```